# HTTP Request Not found error windows phone

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, windows-phone-7

I have a HTML page hosted on a local Apache server and I'm trying to make a HTTP web request to the page using the below code. The code runs into a web exception, and throws an `invalid argument exception` too. This happens in the piece of code used to  get the data from the stream in the catch section of the  code:

```
 private void b1_Click_1(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {

        System.Uri targetUri = new System.Uri(@"http://192.168.1.4/san/index1.html");
        HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)HttpWebRequest.Create(targetUri);
        request.BeginGetResponse(new AsyncCallback(ReadWebRequestCallback), request); 

    }


    private void ReadWebRequestCallback(IAsyncResult callbackResult)
    {
        HttpWebRequest myRequest = (HttpWebRequest)callbackResult.AsyncState;


        try
        {
            HttpWebResponse myResponse = (HttpWebResponse)myRequest.EndGetResponse(callbackResult);
            using (StreamReader httpwebStreamReader = new StreamReader(myResponse.GetResponseStream()))
            {
                string results = httpwebStreamReader.ReadToEnd();
                //TextBlockResults.Text = results; //-- on another thread!
                // Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(() => TextBlockResults.Text = results);


            }
            myResponse.Close();

        }
        catch (WebException ex)
        {
            using (StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(ex.Response.GetResponseStream()))
            {
                Debug.WriteLine(reader.ReadToEnd());
            }


        }



    }
```

Comment: the  the url used returns s html page when pinged from the browser, but the same url does not return any response from the ie in the phone emulator, is it the issue with the Apache set up

Answer (score 0):

Are you trying to access the page from the emulator or the device? If it's the device, you need to make sure that the web page is accessible from a secondary device. That is - make sure that port 80 is open for LAN access.

Comment: Hi Den . i am trying access the page from the emulator

Comment: "Works in the browser" - do you mean IE in the emulator? Do you have internet access in the emulator? What version of the SDK are you using?

Comment: Works in the Browser of my laptop,  does not work in the IE of the Emulator, i do have internet access in my emulator,i use the sdk8.0

Comment: Check this first: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/jj681694(v=vs.105).aspx#BKMK_CannotconnecttoInternetdestinations